# How to fire just one result from a couple of emits in Kotlin coroutine flow?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I have a flow like this:

```
fun createRawDataFlow() = callbackFlow<String> {
    SensorProProvider.getInstance(this@MainActivity).registerDataCallback { sensorProDeviceInfo, bytes ->
        val dataString = bytes.map { it.toString() }.reduce { acc, s -> "$acc, $s" }
        val hexString = HEXUtils.byteToHex(bytes)
        Log.e("onDataReceived", "deviceInfo: ${sensorProDeviceInfo.deviceIdentify}, dataSize:${bytes.size}, data:$dataString")
        offer(hexString)
    }
    awaitClose {  }
}


GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    createRawDataFlow()
        .map {
            Log.e("onDataReceived", "map2: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            // what I want is collecting 10 emits of sensor's data, and return a list of them
            // arraylistOf<String>(/* 10 hexStrings here*/)
        }
        .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
        .collect {
            Log.e("onDataReceived", "thread: ${Thread.currentThread().name}, hexData:$it")
        }
}
```

Just like the comment in the code. I wanna collect 10 hex strings from the flow because of these strings come from the same period of time, and then pack them in an array list for return. How can I achieve this? Is there any operator similar to map to do this? Btw, forgive my poor English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a batch collection, and you do not wanna cancel the original flow, you could adjust your emitting flow function in a way that it holds a cache for the values.

```kotlin
/*
 * Returns a list of at least [batchSize] integers.
 */
fun aFlow(cacheSize: Int = 10): Flow<List<Int>> {
  var counter: Int = 0
  val cache: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()

  return flow {
    while(currentCoroutineContext().isActive) {
      cache.add(counter++)

      if (cache.size >= cacheSize) {
        emit(cache)
        cache.clear()
      }

      delay(500L) // the delay is just to simulate incoming sensor data
    }
  }
}
```

**Generic Solution**

To make this a bit more generic I created a generic extension function on flow you can apply to any Flow you wanna have a batch list returned.

Consider we have an `infiniteFlow` of integers:

```kotlin
fun infiniteFlow(): Flow<Int> {
    var counter: Int = 0

    return flow {
        while (currentCoroutineContext().isActive) {
            emit(counter++)
            delay(250L) // the delay is just to simulate incoming sensor data
        }
    }
}
```

And this `batch` extension function:

```kotlin
/**
 * Maps the Flow<T> to Flow<List<T>>. The list size is at least [batchSize]
 */
fun <T> Flow<T>.batch(batchSize: Int = 10): Flow<List<T>> {
    val cache: MutableList<T> = mutableListOf()

    return map {
        cache.apply { add(it) }
    }.filter { it.size >= batchSize }
        .map {
            mutableListOf<T>().apply { // copy the list and clears the cache
                addAll(cache)
                cache.clear()
            }
        }
}
```

*Note: This is just an example. It is not optimized or tested for edge-cases!*

You can then use this function like:

```kotlin
infiniteFlow().batch(batchSize = 12).collect { println(it) }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. I believe this is what I want. What matter is this solution really help me opening my mind.

Comment: It's three years after your answer and no official method has been introduced yet. Any updates or better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First you apply [take](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/take.html)

```kotlin
fun <T> Flow<T>.take(count: Int): Flow<T>
```

> Returns a flow that contains first count elements. When count elements are consumed, the original flow is cancelled. Throws IllegalArgumentException if count is not positive.

Then you apply [toCollection](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/to-collection.html)

```kotlin
suspend fun <T, C : MutableCollection<in T>> Flow<T>.toCollection(destination: C): C
```

> Collects given flow into a destination

Between `take` and `toCollection` you can place other operations if you need. This is how it looks all together:

```kotlin
val hexList: List<String> = createRawDataFlow().take(10) // take first 10 items
  .map { ... } // do some (optional) mapping
  .toCollection(mutableListOf())

// after the flow is cancelled (all items consumed) you have the elements in hexList
```

**Documentation**

- [Flow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/index.html)

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. I think I am not doing well in describing my question. Your solution works fine indeed the first 10 items, but the situation is that the sensor continually sends data  until I quit my app, so the original flow should not be cancelled and keep handling the coming pack of 10 strings at some time.

Comment: I red the document about buffer but I am not sure about whether can it do the trick because I never used that before.

Comment: No problem. The only solution I can see here is to adjust the emitting flow and introduce a cache there. I updated my answer to give an example for this.